# Ошибка считывания и обработки данных HTML-формы на JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите, функция рабочая, но нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки `проверить` считывались заполненные данные в `input`-ах и выполнялся скрипт. Не понимаю, почему не работает.

```js
function validate(form) {
  if (Math.pow((x - x0), 2) + Math.pow((y - y0), 2) > Math.pow(R, 2) && x > x0 - R && x < x0 + R && y > y0 - R && y < y0 + R) {
    alert("Точка находится между окружностью и сторонами квадрата");
  } else {
    alert("Точка не находится между окружностью и сторонами квадрата");
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>
          <input name="x" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <td>y</td>
      <td>
        <input name="y" type="text">
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>x0</td>
        <td>
          <input name="x0" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>y0</td>
        <td>
          <input name="y0" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>
          <input name="R" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="validate(this.form)" value="Проверить">
  </form>
```

Comment: Прийдется вам почитать основы js в контексте HTML

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/form-elements изучите материалы этого сайта. Ваш вопрос не очень сложный, но означает незнание как работает javascript в браузере. Т.е. слишком общий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала у вас есть ошибка в HTML-коде. У вас пропущен открывающий тег `<tr>`.
Во-вторых, в самом конце JS-кода лишняя точка с запятой.
В-третьих, пропущена закрывающая фигурная скобка для функции в конце кода.
И наконец - откуда вы берёте эти переменные `x`, `x0`, и т.д.? Вы их не создали и не присвоили им значение. Да, у вас есть форма в объекте, но вы не можете обращаться к элементам внутри этого объекта. Вам надо их сначала "найти". Но так как мы используем нативный JS, то будем искать не в самом объекте `form`, а в DOM-дереве страницы.
Вот ваш код полностью исправленный:

```js
function validate(form) {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("x");
  var y = document.getElementsByName("y");
  var x0 = document.getElementsByName("x0");
  var y0 = document.getElementsByName("y0");
  var R = document.getElementsByName("R");
  if (Math.pow((x - x0), 2) + Math.pow((y - y0), 2) > Math.pow(R, 2) && x > x0 - R && x < x0 + R && y > y0 - R && y < y0 + R) {
    alert("Точка находится между окружностью и сторонами квадрата");
  } else {
    alert("Точка не находится между окружностью и сторонами квадрата");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>
          <input name="x" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>
          <input name="y" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>x0</td>
        <td>
          <input name="x0" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>y0</td>
        <td>
          <input name="y0" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>
          <input name="R" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="validate(this.form)" value="Проверить">
  </form>
```

Comment: спасибо добрый человек

Comment: @Алещка13 да не за что. Хорошей вам учёбы и удачи в нашем нелёгкой жизни программистов. ;)